# How can I add Facebook contact event code to AMP page?

Tags: amp-html, facebook-pixel

I am trying to add facebook contact event_code to my valid AMP page (propertywebservices.ca) so that i can track the calls i receive through my facebook ads.

AMP pages do not allow the required facebook scripts below;

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'Contact');
</script>

<button id="contactButton">Contact</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('contactButton').addEventListener('click', 
function() {
insert_event_code_here;
...
}, false);
</script>
```

Is there a way to work around this problem ?

Also, what code would I enter for "insert_event_code_here;" ?

Thanks for any help,

I found a solution that uses google tag manager to add the required scripts which required a custom_html tag but the only custom tag I see in the tag manager is custom_image, I presume the custom_html tag has been removed.

This is how I have added facebook pixel to my page:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<amp-pixel src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=MY- 
ID&ev=PageView&noscript=1" layout="nodisplay"></amp-pixel>
```

I found this code on stachoverflow.com, it seems to be the best way AMP accepts the pixel.

I want to be able to view the phone calls i receive from facebook ads in facebook event manager the same way I can see the page views.